# GameCenter notification banner appears "squished" sometimes - what could be causing this?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, notifications, game-center

I have an app that uses GameCenter in a very simple way (just a simple leaderboard with an all time high score). Sometimes when I switch to my app I'll see the notification saying "welcome back to Game Center" but sometimes this notification appears squished like in the following image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k0Io.jpg

Does anybody know what might the causing this? Because I have absolutely no idea.

My authentication code which generates the notification banner is fairly standard.

```
GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

    [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error) {
        // If there is an error, do not assume local player is not authenticated.
        if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated) {

            // Enable Game Center Functionality
            self.gameCenterAuthenticationComplete = YES;
            [self enableGameCenter:YES];
            gameCenterButton.enabled=true;

        } else {
            NSLog(@"game center not logged in");
            // User has logged out of Game Center or can not login to Game Center, your app should run
            // without GameCenter support or user interface.
            self.gameCenterAuthenticationComplete = NO;
            [self enableGameCenter:NO];
            [self presentViewController:viewController animated:true completion:nil ];
            gameCenterButton.enabled=false;

        }
    };
```

One additional piece of information is that my app is in portrait orientation when this problem occurs. It seems like if I rotate my phone 90 degrees while the banner is showing, it will look normally in landscape but in portrait it looks all squished. Does this help explain it?

Comment: Can you post some code that controls the view on the screen at the time?

Comment: I added the code which generates the notification to my original question but I'm not sure if there's anything g about it that would explain the weird squished banner.

Comment: Here's a clue... My app is in portrait orientation when this problem happens. It seems like if I rotate my phone 90 degrees while the banner is showing, it will look normally in landscape but in portrait it looks all squished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I hadn't implemented preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation so I did that

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

And also I made sure that supportedInterfaceOrientations returend UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait (note that it returns UIInterfaceOrientationMASKPortrait not just UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait). After that everything worked fine.

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return  UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```